# how to access the properties of the parent object?

Tags: javascript

please help solve the problem.

i make 3 objects:

level:

```
var Level = function() { 
  self = this;
  this.cellsObserver = new CellsObserver();
  console.log('co from level ' + this.cellsObserver);
  this.fieldObj = new Field();
}
```

field:

```
var Field = function() { 
  self = this;
  this.init();
};

Field.prototype = Object.create(Level.prototype);

Field.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    console.log('co from field ' + self.cellsObserver);
  } 
 }
```

observer:

```
var CellsObserver = function(){
  .............
}
```

in result console output follow:

> co from level [object Object] co from field undefined

I do not understand why in the second case output 'undefined'. because I have appointed a parent:

```
Field.prototype = Object.create(Level.prototype);
```

Comment: It's fairly obvious you don't understand prototypial inheritance (and a few other JavaScript concepts). I suggest you read some tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr:** there is no field cellsObserver neither in Field or Level.prototype object. And there is no such thing as a classical 'self' in Javascript.

**The long story.**

When you're trying to fetch `object.property`, the Javascript will look at the object trying to find `property`, then to the `object.prototype` (which is another object) and so on until it get to the null prototype in the `Object.prototype` reference.

So, when you're calling second time the `this.cellsObserver` in Level constructor function, it goes like this:
`this` is a just new constructed object (if it called with the `new` keyword), and there is `cellsObserver` in the property list, so it'll be fetched without any deep lookup.

Then,

```
Field.prototype = Object.create(Level.prototype);
```

This only means that `Field.prototype` now will refer to a new object, which properties are the same as in `Level.prototype` in that moment.
From your code, there are no non-standard properties in `Level.prototype` object (you didn't provide any).

Then,

```
self = this;
```

Here you just assigning a global variable called `self` a reference to the just created object or window object ([it depends](http://tobyho.com/2010/11/22/javascript-constructors-and/)). If you wish to store a reference to the `this` object, you should `var`: `var self = this`. But you should remember that this `self` variable could be accessed only in the scope where is was declared or in a closure.

Then,

```
Field.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    console.log('co from field ' + self.cellsObserver);
  } 
 }
```

First of all, here you just override the previos instruction (`Field.prototype = Object.create(Level.prototype);`). If you want to extend the `Field.prototype` object, you could do in the `Object.create` call [in second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), or just by accessing a property like that: `Field.prototype.init = function(){...}`.

Second. The `self` variable could contain anything when the `init` function will be executed. Just use `this` for the current object here.

Third. Let's try to guess what will happen when `this.cellsObserver` get evaluated inside this `init` function.

The `this` object is referring to the `Field` instance, and there is no `cellsObserver` property there, so we move to the `Field.prototype` object, which is defined above (`{ init: function () {...}}`), there is no `cellsObserver` either, so we move to the `Object.prototype` object, which is `null`. Ok, our lookup is failed, `this.cellsObserver` is undefined.

What would be it look like if the `Field.prototype = Object.create(Level.prototype)` wasn't been overridden by the following code? The `this` object will refer to the Field instance as early. The Field.prototype is referring to the object which is copy of the `Level.prototype` object, and there is no `cellsObserver` here either. So, we look to the `Object.prototype`, and that's it. There is no `cellsObserver` in any objects except in the instances on Level class, which isn't referenced in any way in the `Field` instances.

You can play with that here: http://www.objectplayground.com/ by pasting this code:

```
var Level = function() {
  this.cellsObserver = new CellsObserver();
  this.fieldObj = new Field();
}

var Field = function() {
  this.init();
};

Field.prototype = Object.create(Level.prototype);

Field.prototype.init = function() {};

this.field = new Field();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the `Field.prototype`. Just assign to `Field.prototype.init`.